# two swaps in permutations of a string?

Tags: string, recursion, permutation

Can someone exactly explain why do we need to undo the swap in the algorithm of finding all permutations of string??

```
swap((a+i), (a+j));  // Make a[j] the start of this (sub-)permutation starting at i.
permute(a, i+1, n);  // Find the permuations of a[i+1..n] - and undo them.
swap((a+i), (a+j));  // Undo the swap of a[i] and a[j].
```

Comment: What programming language is this ? and What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Post the full algorithm

Comment: Since the array "a" is global and will get modified by each call to permute.  Better way to understand would be take a small example of 4 characters and try with & without the last line.

Comment: You will likely find http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/ to be a good reference. Section 7.1.2.1 in particular.  http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/perms.pdf too.